# Proxybroker IndexError

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.5, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to use the python package proxybroker.
I tried to use one of the examples mentioned here. I just copied the following example to run locally:

> ```
> import asyncio from proxybroker import Broker
>
>
> async def save(proxies, filename):
>     """Save proxies to a file."""
>     with open(filename, 'w') as f:
>         while True:
>             proxy = await proxies.get()
>             if proxy is None:
>                 break
>             proto = 'https' if 'HTTPS' in proxy.types else 'http'
>             row = '%s://%s:%d\n' % (proto, proxy.host, proxy.port)
>             f.write(row)
>
>
> def main():
>     proxies = asyncio.Queue()
>     broker = Broker(proxies)
>     tasks = asyncio.gather(broker.find(types=['HTTP', 'HTTPS'], limit=10),
>                            save(proxies, filename='proxies.txt'))
>     loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
>     loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
>
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     main()
> ```

When I try to run the code the following error is thrown together with some deprecation warnings:

> ```
> /home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/STW/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:494:
> DeprecationWarning: Use async with instead   warnings.warn("Use async
> with instead", DeprecationWarning)
> /home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/STW/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:494:
> DeprecationWarning: Use async with instead   warnings.warn("Use async
> with instead", DeprecationWarning)
> /home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/STW/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:494:
> DeprecationWarning: Use async with instead   warnings.warn("Use async
> with instead", DeprecationWarning)
> /home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/STW/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:494:
> DeprecationWarning: Use async with instead   warnings.warn("Use async
> with instead", DeprecationWarning)
> /home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/STW/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:494:
> DeprecationWarning: Use async with instead   warnings.warn("Use async
> with instead", DeprecationWarning)
> /home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/STW/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:494:
> DeprecationWarning: Use async with instead   warnings.warn("Use async
> with instead", DeprecationWarning)
> /home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/STW/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:494:
> DeprecationWarning: Use async with instead   warnings.warn("Use async
> with instead", DeprecationWarning)
> /home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/STW/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:494:
> DeprecationWarning: Use async with instead   warnings.warn("Use async
> with instead", DeprecationWarning)
> /home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/STW/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:494:
> DeprecationWarning: Use async with instead   warnings.warn("Use async
> with instead", DeprecationWarning)
> /home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/STW/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:494:
> DeprecationWarning: Use async with instead   warnings.warn("Use async
> with instead", DeprecationWarning) https://getproxy.net/en/ is failed.
> Error: ClientOSError(101, 'Cannot connect to host getproxy.net:443
> ssl:True [Can not connect to getproxy.net:443 [Network is
> unreachable]]'); https://getproxy.net/en/ is failed. Error:
> ClientOSError(101, 'Cannot connect to host getproxy.net:443 ssl:True
> [Can not connect to getproxy.net:443 [Network is unreachable]]');
> https://getproxy.net/en/ is failed. Error: ClientOSError(101, 'Cannot
> connect to host getproxy.net:443 ssl:True [Can not connect to
> getproxy.net:443 [Network is unreachable]]'); Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/testing/test/test_prox.py", line 27,
> in 
>     main()   File "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/testing/test/test_prox.py", line 23,
> in main
>     loop.run_until_complete(tasks)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 387, in
> run_until_complete
>     return future.result()   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
>     raise self._exception   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 241, in _step
>     result = coro.throw(exc)   File "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/STW/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/proxybroker/api.py",
> line 108, in find
>     await self._run(self._checker.check_judges(), action)   File "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/STW/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/proxybroker/api.py",
> line 114, in _run
>     await tasks   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 361, in __iter__
>     yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 296, in _wakeup
>     future.result()   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
>     raise self._exception   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 241, in _step
>     result = coro.throw(exc)   File "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/STW/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/proxybroker/checker.py",
> line 26, in check_judges
>     await asyncio.gather(*[j.check() for j in self._judges])   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 361, in __iter__
>     yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 296, in _wakeup
>     future.result()   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
>     raise self._exception   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
>     result = coro.send(None)   File "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/STW/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/proxybroker/judge.py",
> line 82, in check
>     j=self, code=resp.status, page=page[0], IndexError: string index out of range
> ```

I use python3.5.2 and the up to date versions of proxybroker (0.1.4) aiohttp (1.0.2) asyncio (3.4.3).

I'm not sure what causes the error as I did not change the code example and as far as I know I have installed all dependencies. Can anyone help me and tell me what I am doing wrong and even better how to do it right?

**EDIT**
A quick workaround for the issue is to change the line where the error occurs. That line is only for logging an error, thus the change should not do any harm.
For this workaround - not a solution -  I added an additional check in the judge.py in line 79 where the exception was raised before. 
Locally I changed  it to:

```
        if isinstance(page, type(list())) or isinstance(page, type(dict())):
            log.error(('{j} is failed. HTTP status code: {code}; '
                       'Real IP on page: {ip}; Version: {word}; '
                       'Response: {page}').format(
                j=self, code=resp.status, page=page[0],
                ip=(get_my_ip() in page), word=(rv in page)))
        else:
            log.error(('{j} is failed. HTTP status code: {code}; '
                       'Real IP on page: {ip}; Version: {word}; '
                       'Response: {page}').format(
                      j=self, code=resp.status, page=page,
                      ip=(get_my_ip() in page), word=(rv in page)))
```

That way I can use proxybroker again. The issue is filed on gihub with [proxybroker](https://github.com/constverum/ProxyBroker/issues/23).

Answer (score 0):

Deprecation warnings are harmless (at least unless I'll remove this kind of backward compatibility).

The error just says that `getproxy.net` is not available -- this is your main problem.

Comment: So is there anything I can do about it, because if I try to reach `getproxy.net` via browser the site is available.

Comment: I don't know. Try to make an issue in https://github.com/constverum/ProxyBroker/issues

Comment: Thank you for your help. To be able to work on I am currently implementing a fallback that makes use of another python package called [freeproxy](https://github.com/yieldnull/freeproxy). This seems to be a very good alternative, that finds quite some proxies (above 5000, although not yet tested for status) as well and above all is very easy to extend. So for everyone else itnerested in alteratives this is the place to go.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is problem with:

```
<Judge [HTTP] www.ingosander.net> is failed. HTTP status code: 302; Real IP on page: False; Version: False; Response:
```

The response content is empty because it's redirected (status code: 302).

Possible solutions:
1. Change http client. Use requests pakage - automaticly follows redirects.
2. Change error logging for redirected urls adding

```
elif (resp.status == 302):
    log.error(('{j} is failed. HTTP status code: {code}; '
               'Real IP on page: {ip}; Version: {word}; '
               'Response: {page}').format(
              j=self, code=resp.status, page=None,
              ip=(get_my_ip() in page), word=(rv in page)))
```

in the judge.py

3. Comment this Judge in the judgeList at the bottom of judge.py